# Display data from mysql in html via php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
// require('db.php');
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("alphaindia");
//SELECT Id, Name FROM coursetype where isDeleted=0
  $result = mysql_query("Call GetCourseTypes()");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["Id"], $row["Name"]);


  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      //  printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["Id"], $row["Name"]);

       echo  "<a href='UploadCourse/Step2.php?id=$row['Id']&name=$row['Name']'>$row['Id']</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;$row['Name']<br />";
   }
```

I am getting a blank page when i try and run the above code.

Please help i am new to php

Comment: Check your apache `error.log` file

Comment: There is no issue with the error log

Comment: Is that all your code ? What else do you have ?

Comment: printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["Id"], $row["Name"]);

Comment: why two while loops?and where is the closing bracket of first while loop?also use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, concatenation issues in below line

```
 echo  "<a href='UploadCourse/Step2.php?id=".$row['Id']."&name=".$row['Name']."'>".$row['Id']."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['Name']."<br />";
```

instead of

```
 echo  "<a href='UploadCourse/Step2.php?id=$row['Id']&name=$row['Name']'>$row['Id']</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;$row['Name']<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

please try.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   //  printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["Id"], $row["Name"]);
   echo  "<a href='UploadCourse/Step2.php?id={$row['Id']}&name={$row['Name']}'>{$row['Id']}</a>{$row['Name']}<br />"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without encapsulating field names with single quotes "'":

`echo  "<a href='UploadCourse/Step2.php?id=$row[Id]&name=$row[Name]'>$row[Id]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;$row[Name]<br />";`